# Android cannot use google libraries

Tags: java, android, eclipse, api

I'm sorry if this has been asked a million times, though I have read the responses and documentation and as far as I know everything is by the book in my application.

I cannot import google libraries.

My applications build path (Right click proejct > properties > build path > android) is set to use Google APIs ver 4.0.3 (because of v2 api's could this be the cause of the error? I hope not as my test device is running 4.1.1)

I have declared

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

in the manifest, am I missing something?

For example when I attempt to import

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
```

I am told the import cannot be resolved

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: I have edited my post to explain my error

Answer (score 0):

> am I missing something?

You have `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />`, which is for Maps V1, not Maps V2.

> I am told the import cannot be resolved

That is because you have not [attached the Play Services SDK Android library project to your application](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html).

Comment: I have setup google play services and referenced it from within my project, do I also have to delete that line from my manifest? Its still not working however..

Comment: @fr0s1yjack: "do I also have to delete that line from my manifest?" -- it is not necessary and may interfere with your app being installed on some otherwise-compatible devices. "Its still not working however" -- if your problem is the same as before, then there is something wrong with how you attached the Play Services SDK to your project.